# Connect to PostgreSql using PHP where there is a TLS Certificate

Tags: php, postgresql, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am working with IBM Cloud foundary and I created an instance of PostgreSql which has a TLS Certifcate and PHP cloudfoundary instance.
I have been searching on internet and there are almost no related information regarding this.

So far my code is

```
function exception_error_handler($errno,$errstr,$errfile,$errline){
    throw new ErrorException($errstr,$errno,0,$errfile,$errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
try{
    $conn = @pg_connect("host=dbhost user=dbuser dbname=dbname password=dbpass sslmode='require-full');
}
catch(Exception $e){
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: And what happens?

Comment: I checked the log files and found that postgre SQL modules are not added, but I haven't found a way to add those dependencies/modules in cloudfoundry

Comment: Instructions for enabling extensions with the PHP buildpack: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/php/gsg-php-config.html#php-extensions. Aside from enabling the extensions your app requires, the way you connect should be exactly as you'd do if you deployed to a VM or elsewhere.